# Why isn't DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH being propagated here?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, environment-variables

I have a simple C++ program that I'm trying to run that is linked against a version of the Boost.Thread library that I built previously. I seem to be having trouble understanding the way that runtime library paths behave on OS X.

Since my Boost library doesn't have an [RPATH-relative install name](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/RunpathDependentLibraries.html), I'm using the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable to tell the dynamic linker where to find `libboost_thread.dylib` at runtime.

This works fine if I run the program directly in my (`bash`) shell:

```
[~/git/project]$ echo $DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
/Users/jasonr/git/project/boost/lib
[~/git/project]$ .sconf_temp/conftest_7
[~/git/project]$ # Program runs successfully; this is what I expect.
```

However, this program is run as part of a series of tests by an `autoconf`-like framework that I'm using. It runs the program in a child shell using `sh -c`. Here's what happens if I try that:

```
[~/git/project]$ # Make sure the environment variable is exported to child shells.
[~/git/project]$ export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
[~/git/project]$ # Try to run it in a child shell.
[~/git/project]$ sh -c .sconf_temp/conftest_7
dyld: Library not loaded: libboost_thread.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/jasonr/git/project/.sconf_temp/conftest_7
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

It's as if the environment variable isn't propagated to `dyld` in this case. Why would this occur? I'm more familiar with the behavior of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` on Linux, which (I think) should work with the above example. Is there something else I need to do in order to make this work?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Presumably, you are running El Capitan (OS X 10.11) or later.  It's a side effect of System Integrity Protection. From the [System Integrity Protection Guide: Runtime Protections](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/RuntimeProtections/RuntimeProtections.html) article:

> When a process is started, the kernel checks to see whether the main
>   executable is protected on disk or is signed with an special system
>   entitlement. If either is true, then a flag is set to denote that it
>   is protected against modification. …
>
> … Any dynamic linker (`dyld`)
>   environment variables, such as `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`, are purged when
>   launching protected processes.

All of the system-provided interpreters, including `/bin/sh`, are protected in this fashion. Therefore, when you invoke `sh`, all DYLD_* environment variables are purged.

You could write a shell script which sets `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and then executes `.sconf_temp/conftest_7`. You can use the the shell interpreter to execute that — indeed, you must — and the environment variable will be fine, since the purging happens when a protected executable is started. Basically, this approach is analogous to the working example in your question, but encapsulated in a shell script.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. This is a particularly onerous limitation for developers IMHO. As you pointed out, I could write a shell script that sets the environment variables first. However, that requires me to hard-code the values into the script, as there's no good way to communicate them into the script in question (as they're stripped out of the environment). Seems like turning off SIP is the easiest workaround.