# Using Matlab runtime on Mac and Linux

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use MCR to run an executable file that I created using

```
mcc -mv mycode.m
```

I installed MCR (2017a Matlab) for Mac from here https://uk.mathworks.com/products/compiler/matlab-runtime.html. After this, I edited the `.bashrc` file to set the path as instructed at the end of installation by:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v92/runtime/maci64:/Applications/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v92/sys/os/maci64:/Applications/MATLAB/MATLAB_Runtime/v92/bin/maci64
```

After the above I typed in terminal to run the executable file as:

```
sh mycode.sh
```

But this gives the following message

> Usage: mycode.sh deployedMCRroot args

Can anyone help me with what I may be missing here?

I am right now installing MCR on the same machine on which I used MATLAB to 
generate executable file.  I am doing this to test the output file.

Comment: If you are on "El Capitan" or later, `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` won't work the same way it did before. I'm not sure if this use case would be affected, but I presume so. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35568122/why-isnt-dyld-library-path-being-propagated-here

Answer (score 1):

`deployedMCRroot` refers to the directory in which you installed the `MCR`. Supposing that your script doesn't require any additional argument, if you installed `MCR` under `/Applications/MCR/`, you should type the following command in order to make your script work:

```
sh mycode.sh /Applications/MCR/
```

Normally, at installation time, the `MCR` framework is installed in the chosen directory but placed into a subfolder describing its version. So it's possible that you may be required the correct `MCR` framework specifying the proper version as follows:

```
sh mycode.sh /Applications/MCR/v70/
```